# Decorators: make actions after function is awaited

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, decorator, python-decorators

I use Python 3.7 and have following decorator:

```
def decorator(success_check: function):
    def wrap(func):
        async def inner(root, info, **args):
            func_result = await func(root, info, **args)
            if not success_check(func_result):
                pass # do some action
            return func(root, info, **args)
        return inner
    return wrap
```

In a current implementation func is awaited two times. Can I make it work with func awaited once?

Comment: Why do you return `func(root, info, **args)` instead of `func_result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you call `return await func(root, info, **args)`, or, event better, just do `return func_result`, most likely, it will solve your issue